# database integration between 2 software applications

Tags: mysql-connector

I just want to export/import data between 2 database applicaitons, So I was just wondering if it is possible and what process I have to go through. Would I be able to perform such operation using MySQL server?

I tried using MySQL, but I think it is not possible, so if anybody has any suggestion where to start, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If the 2 applications not use update or use with separate tables:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html

```sql
SELECT a,b,a+b INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/data.txt'
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
  FROM test_table;
```

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html

```sql
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/data.txt' INTO TABLE db2.my_table;
```

If require update, then maybe load it into temporary tables and process it with further queries from there.

Comment: how about to mass uplaod into a database software?

Comment: I have a database software, and was wondering if I can do a mass upload of a csv file into it.